# Asp.net Mvc custom content managed regions like webforms user controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, webforms, user-controls

In asp.net web forms we have user controls as reusable components for pages. These user controls can be passed values externally through public properties e.g. on a web form we can drop this user control to display a text which came from db (like content managed system) by setting key as public property to this user control and it will pull the value. ( this key, value can be stored in application cache as list or dictionary to avoid DB round trips).

I want to implement same idea in asp.net mvc, but new to it. Any expert suggestion to implement same idea will be very helpful? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of a user control is a PartialView; there are two ways to use a partial view.  The first is to define a partial in the view itself:

```
@Html.Partial("NameOfViewInControllerFolder", ModelForPartialview)
```

The second way is have an action method that returns a partial view:

```
public ActionResult X()
{
   return PartialView("NameOfView");
}
```

And from your view use:

```
@Html.Action("X", "ControllerName")
```

And that will call the action method, and insert the results.  To ensure that action is only called within the a view, you can use the [ChildActionOnly] attribute.

If an action method, you can use JQuery to request it via AJAX, and load the results into a view:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET|POST", 
    url: "@Url.Action("X", "ControllerName")", 
    success: function(d) { /* d is HTML */ });
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. Web form constructs the full page through single http request even there are many user controls on it. But above solution looks to be making a separate ajax call. In my case there might be 100's of these small partial views fed by simple string. Looking for an optimised solution really.

Comment: I gave you two options, and noted that there is an AJAX benefit (not a requirement).  Please reread above carefully.

Comment: Thanks Brian. will research on this option.